# How to view a column values in comma separated string with group by clause using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

How can I get U_ProductType column with comma separated string in following SQL query (in SQL Server 2014). It needs to group by DocNum and don't need Null values in U_ProductType when it converted as a comma separated string. I tried "FOR XML PATH" option also. Here is my query for your reference,

```
SELECT
    ORDR.DocNum, ORDR.CardCode, ORDR.CardName, ORDR.SlpCode,
    OSLP.SlpName, OITM.U_Product_Type,
    SUM (RDR1.LineTotal) LineTotal,
    ISNULL (SUM (DPI1.LineTotal), 0) dwpnt
FROM
    ORDR
INNER JOIN 
    RDR1 ON RDR1.DocEntry = ORDR.DocEntry   
LEFT JOIN 
    OITM ON OITM.ItemCode = RDR1.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN 
    OSLP ON OSLP.SlpCode = ORDR.SlpCode
LEFT JOIN 
    DPI1 ON DPI1.BaseEntry = RDR1.DocEntry 
         AND DPI1.TargetType <> 14 
         AND DPI1.BaseLine = RDR1.LineNum
LEFT JOIN 
    RCT2 ON RCT2.DocEntry = DPI1.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN  
    ORCT ON RCT2.DocNum = ORCT.DocEntry AND ORCT.Canceled = 'N'
WHERE 
    ORDR.CANCELED = 'N' 
    AND ISNULL (DPI1.LineTotal, 0) = 0 
    AND ORDR.SlpCode = 67
GROUP BY 
    ORDR.DocNum, ORDR.CardCode, ORDR.CardName, ORDR.SlpCode,
    OSLP.SlpName, OITM.U_Product_Type
```

Result and my requirement as follows,

[image: table]

Comment: update your question and add a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: @scaisEdge I have attached an image here with query result and expected results.Please click 'enter image description here' link. I am a new comer and still not have permission to attach a image. link has provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `STUFF()` as shown below. Just replace `cte` with your original query. Another way is to create a temp table with your current result and replace that `cte` with the temp table newly created.

```
SELECT DoNum
        , CardCode
        , CardName
        , SipCode
        , SlpName
        , STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,U_Product_Type) 
         FROM [cte] t1
         WHERE (DoNum = cte.DoNum
         and CardCode = t1.CardCode
         and CardName = t1.CardName
         and SipCode = t1.SipCode
         and SlpName = t1.SlpName) 
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS U_Product_Type
         ,sum(LineTotal) as LineTotal
         ,sum(dwpnt) as dwpnt
FROM cte
group by DoNum
, CardCode
, CardName
, SipCode
, SlpName
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e5182ec9e369571711f1b5308566a04)